# What does it mean to "type `2' " to undo an automatic unwanted correction? where am I supposed to type this?

Tags: errors

What does it mean to "type `2' " to undo an automatic unwanted correction?  where am I supposed to type this?

This dialogue comes up when I try to execute code for which it says a curly bracket { has been inserted BUT I AM SURE IT IS NOT NEEDED, and it says if i type `2'  then the insertion will be eliminated and compiling will continue.  But I don't know where I am supposed to type this!   Argh!   Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Close voters: The linked question asks about a specific error. This question asks about interaction with the engine, which has probably been hidden from the OP by a nasty IDE. The two are quite different in my opinion.

Comment: Presumably you are compiling online, from a command line, and the compilation has halted at a prompt. "type `2`" means exactly what it says: at the prompt, type `2`.  This will remove the last 2 characters read from your input file and restart the compilation. (This is all explained in *The TeXbook*.) Although the compilation will continue, it's not guaranteed that no more errors are present.  (To halt the compilation completely, and preserve the log for examination, type `x`.  You really want to preserve the log; it will contain useful information that can't easily be obtained otherwise.)

Comment: I feel like this would be more answerable if we knew what IDE "it" was.

Comment: @Teepeemm --- It doesn't matter. They are all evil.

Comment: @Frank, people speculated here you are using a command line for compilation. If so, please add this to your comment, perhaps assisted by a screenshot. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The original (and still the best in my opinion!) way to compile a document using `tex` (or a descendant such as `pdftex`) is to call it from the command line. Thus, you prepare a file called `whatever.tex`, and in the command terminal type

```
tex whatever.tex
```

or perhaps

```
latex whatever.tex
```

The engine then attempts to process your file and produces a dvi or pdf file if it succeeds. If it runs into trouble, the engine might produce an error, or it might prompt the user for further input. The option to type 2 is one case of this. Here is an example showing `pdflatex` running from the command line.

[image]

The code I used for this as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\( {abc \)
\end{document}
```

Many modern tex editors put a layer of obfuscation over this, so you press a button to invoke the engine (which actually just executes a command similar to the above behind the scenes), and the editor intercepts the engine output.  Most will display some or all of it, though sometimes important information is lost. I don't know if any of them allow you to further interact with the engine, as you could if running from the command line. However, in this case it doesn't matter. The best thing to do is stop the compilation process and fix the error before compiling again.